Powershell use of $sender in a function
I'm new to PS and would like to understand what the $sender variable is and how it works. I have used $this in a function before and that is very straightforward. However I can not for the life of me understand what $sender does or how it behaves when passed to a function. I have tried extensive searching and cannot find any examples of its use. I'm hoping someone can explain what $sender is in laymen's terms and provide an example passed to a function.


The documentation gives a clear explanation of what $sender is. It's an automatic variable that is populated in the context of an Action blocks of cmdlets that deal with event subscription (Register-ObjectEvent, Register-EngineEvent, Register-CimIndicationEvent) and represents the instance that generated the event.
Perhaps 2 examples can help understand it better, for DataAdded event, $sender would be the instance of the PSDataCollection<T>:
try {
    $collection = [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[int]]::new()
    $evt = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $collection -EventName DataAdded -Action {
        "`$sender is of type: '$($sender.GetType())'",
        "Last item added was: '$($sender[-1])'" | Out-Host
    }

    Start-Sleep 1
    $collection.Add(1)

    # On Addition you would see:
    #
    # $sender is of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[int]'
    # Last item added was: '1'
}
finally {
    Unregister-Event $evt.Name
}

In the case of Register-EngineEvent we can customize it as much as we want, for this example we can send a string to the Action block:
try {
    $evt = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MyCustomEvent -Action {
        "`$sender is of type: '$($sender.GetType())'" | Out-Host
    }

    Start-Sleep 1
    $null = New-Event -SourceIdentifier MyCustomEvent -Sender 'hi!'
    # After generating this event we would see that the $sender is a `string`
}
finally {
    Unregister-Event $evt.Name
}

